# js yandex.maps делает нулевую высоту блока ymaps

Tags: yandex-maps-api

не смотря на то я указываю

```html
<div class="board-view-map" style="width: 650px; height: 300px;">
```

тег ymaps, который генерируется внутри, получает style="width: 650px; height: 0px;"

и поэтому не отображается, что я делаю не так?

upd:
вызываю так

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="mapAd" ></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                ymaps.ready(init);

                var myMap, 
                    myPlacemark;

                $( window ).resize(function() {
                  myMap.destroy();  
                  ymaps.ready(init);
                });

                function init(){ 
                    myMap = new ymaps.Map("mapAd", {
                        center: ['.$latitude.', '.$longitude.'],
                        zoom: 14
                    }); 
                    myMap.behaviors.enable("scrollZoom");

                    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(['.$latitude.', '.$longitude.']);

                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                }
            </script>
```

ошибок в консоли нет

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос js-код, который вы используете для создания карты. 
Имеются ли ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: код добавил. ошибок в консоли нет

Comment: А div с классом board-view-map у вас тогда для чего? 

Всё таки style="width: 650px; height: 300px;" нужно указать div'у с id="mapAd".

Comment: указал, но вопрос-то в том, что ширина и высота, как я понял, высчитывается каким-то javascriptом, моя цель в том, чтоб разобраться как управлять этими размерами. повлиять на логику, чтоб был не 0

Comment: Скрипт Яндекс.Карт берёт высоту и ширину из стилей того блока, внутри которого вы пытаетесь вставить карту `<div class="mapAd" style="width: 650px; height: 300px;">`. Пустой блок обычно возникает, если есть какая-то ошибка в вызове карты. Либо какой-то другой скрипт принудительно перебивает высоту mapAd в 0px.

Comment: Как вариант: проверьте, что $latitude и $longitude действительно выводятся и содержат валидные значения.

Comment: Соберите пример на jsfiddle где воспроизводится проблема или дайте ссылку на сайт с проблемой. Скорее всего вы где-то забыли вызвать `map.container.fitToViewport()`. BTW, `center` [должен быть](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#Map__param-state.center) массивом из двух чисел (например `[55.75, 37.62]`), а вас там непонятно что: `center: ['.$latitude.', '.$longitude.']`.